# Java file not writing to output formatter file

Tags: java, output

Please help, I cannot for the life of me figure out why my output file is created, but there is nothing written to it. I read on a similar question that I had to close the output file as the information is buffered and only outputs when the file is closed. I had already done that before reading that post, other than that I cannot find any other post that helps me with this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // creating a File instance to reference text file in Java
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\input.txt");

        //creating a Scanner instance to read File in Java
        Scanner scanfile = new Scanner(inputFile);

        //creating a file to output results of program to
        Formatter outputfile = new Formatter("C:\\output.txt");

        //read each line of file using the Scanner instance "scanfile"
        while (scanfile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanfile.nextLine();

            //splitting String "line" into 2 parts at the ":"
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];

            //splitting part2 into an array of integers at ","
            String[] lineNumString = part2.split(",");
            int[] lineNums = new int[lineNumString.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < lineNumString.length; i++ ) {
                lineNums[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineNumString[i]);
            }

            /*now that we have the line split into an operator (min, max or avg) and an array of numbers
            we can identify the operator with an if and else if statements, then manipulate the integer array according 
            to the operator*/

            //Outputting max value if operator is max
            if (part1 == "max") {
                String outputText = "The Max of " + Arrays.toString(lineNums) + " is " + maxOfArray(lineNums) + ". \r\n";
                outputfile.format("%s", outputText);

            }

            //Outputting min value if operator is min   
            else if (part1 == "min") {
                String outputText = "The Min of " + Arrays.toString(lineNums) + " is " + minOfArray(lineNums) + ". \r\n";
                outputfile.format("%s", outputText);
            }

            //Outputting avg value if operator is avg
            else if (part1 == "avg") {
                String outputText = "The Min of " + Arrays.toString(lineNums) + " is " + avgOfArray(lineNums) + ". \r\n";
                outputfile.format("%s", outputText);

            }

        }
        scanfile.close();
        outputfile.close();
    }

    // print out error messages for input file not found or for being unable to create or write to an output file.
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }



}
// method for determining the max value in an array of integers
public static int maxOfArray(int[] inputArray) {
    int maxValue = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = inputArray[i];
        }

    }
    return maxValue;
}

// method for determining the min value in an array of integers
public static int minOfArray(int[] inputArray) {
    int minValue = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = inputArray[i];
        }

    }
    return minValue;
}

//method for determining avg value of an array of integers
public static int avgOfArray(int[] inputArray) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i : inputArray) {
        sum += i;
    }
    int average = sum / inputArray.length;
    return average;
}
```

}

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is an assignment for school

Comment: I can see that in your `if` statement, you are trying to compare Strings. In this case, you would write `part.equals("min")` as you cannot compare strings using `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare strings using `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` not ==

```
 if (part1.equals("max")) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really do not know how I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are correctly opening/closing the file. However, you are performing direct String comparisons, which means all of your booleans are going to return false every single time - thus resulting in a blank file.

Use `.equals()` when comparing Strings in Java. For example:

`if (part1.equals("max")) {do a thing}`

Comment: Gosh how did I forget this. Thank you.

Comment: I forget it all the time. It's just sort of a quirk with Java.